# How to disable a HIT area in AS2?

Tags: actionscript-2, hittest

How to disable a HIT area (a movieClip with instance name "HIT") in AS2?

Please note that I don't want to hide the hit area after it get hitted. Just needed a code that disable it or remove its instance name so that other objects cannot hit it again.

Comment: Do the answers help you?

Comment: My purpose(Question) is served by another method though your answer helped me in other cases. Many Thanks to you...

Comment: Did you speak about hitArea or hitTest?

Comment: I was talking about disabling instance i.e (c1.onEnterFrame). <br> your_mc.hitArea=null; and your_mc.hitArea=undefined; are not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an instance `c1` to be `disabled` after being touched, you can do:

```
c1.onEnterFrame = function():Void {
    if (this.hitTest(anotherMovieClip)) {
        delete this.onEnterFrame;
    }
}
```

The `hitTest` can't occur after the `onEnterFrame` function is `deleted`.

Comment: Your code is about `hitTest` and not `hitArea`, there is a difference between it.

Comment: @akmozo That's right, my code is about `hitTest area` but not about `hitArea` (`another movie clip to serve as the hit area for a movie clip`). I think the question is about `hitTest`... but I'm perhaps false.

Comment: I think he is speaking about `MovieClip.hitArea`, or may be not ! In both cases, we gave him a solution and that's the most important.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do :

```
your_mc.hitArea = null
```

Or

```
your_mc.hitArea = undefined
```